Powershell Script to pull all computers in an OU that latest Bitlocker Recovery key is older than a specified date
I am trying to write a script that performs the above task.  Specifically, I am looking to pull a list of computer names and recovery key dates, but ONLY if the LATEST recovery key was created before a specific date.
I have the list of computers from the OU in the variable $computers.
So far I am using the below code and I get "error fetching recovery information for "insert computer name here": Directory object not found" for each computer.  Even though it is pulling the distinguished name successfully from the object, so I'm not sure why it would say "directory object not found".

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
Write-Output "Processing computer: $computer"

try {
    $computerObject = Get-ADComputer -Identity $computer -Server "yourdomain.com"
    $computerDN = $computerObject.DistinguishedName
    Write-Output "Computer DistinguishedName: $computerDN"
    
    $recoveryKeys = Get-ADObject -Filter { objectClass -eq "msFVE-RecoveryInformation" } -SearchBase "CN=Microsoft BitLocker Drive Encryption Recovery Information,$computerDN" -Properties WhenCreated, msFVE-RecoveryPassword

    if ($recoveryKeys) {
        $latestKey = $recoveryKeys | Sort-Object WhenCreated -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

        if ($latestKey.WhenCreated -lt $date) {
            Write-Output "Computer: $computer"
            Write-Output "Recovery Key Created: $($latestKey.WhenCreated)"
            Write-Output "Recovery Key: $($latestKey.'msFVE-RecoveryPassword')"
        } else {
            Write-Output "No recovery keys newer than $date found for $computer"
        }
    } else {
        Write-Output "No recovery keys found for $computer"
    }
} catch {
    Write-Output ("Error fetching recovery information for ${computer}: " + $_.Exception.Message)
}
}


Try for debugging : $recoveryData | Sort-Object -Descending -Property DateCreated | Group-Object -Property Name | Format-List  and $recoveryData | Sort-Object -Descending -Property DateCreated | Group-Object -Property Name | foreach { $_ | Format-List }

@jdweng - where is $recoveryData defined?  I do not see this being defined as a variable anywhere in that code.

I added new code that I tried today - I feel that it should work to get the recovery keys, however it is not, it is giving me an error "Error fetching recovery information for ".  Please see my edited post, it is at the very top.

It should be $recoveryKeys.  I copied wrong variable from you code.  When you do not get any data it is usually due to the filters in the query and best to remove filters to debug.

@jdweng can you please look at the most recent code I posted and assist with that?  I have moved way past that original code now.  Thank you.

Try adding $latestKey | format-list  I often use format-list to help with the debugging

I think you want :  $latestKey = $recoveryKeys | Sort-Object WhenCreated -Descending | foreach { $_ | Select-Object -First 1 }

How would that resolve the "directory object not found" error?

@jdweng I think you are confused.  Please see my latest post edits - I have moved on to different code and am receiving a "directory object not found" error.  That is what I am trying to resolve at this point.  Thank you!

I don't see where the error is occurring.  I assumed the error was in the code after $lastestKey was generated and issue was with the contents of $lastestKey.  Did you try $latestKey | format-list

No.  I will place screenshot of the error in the posting.  Thank you @jdweng please take another look.

You are getting an error on the command Get-ADObject.  Remove all the filters and SearchBase and see what happens.  One or more of the properties of the command is causing the object not to be found.  An exception is occurring and you are getting to the catch statement.  Output is occurring from the line Write-Output "Computer DistinguishedName: $computerDN"

But the filters and Searchbase are what are pulling the recovery keys, how would that work if I removed them?

It is just for debugging.  Then type $recoveryKeys to see what is returned.

https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/8bj4il/powershell_to_pull_bitlocker_recovery_most_recent/ This resolved my issue. Great script!

It looks like the issue was with the Get-ADObject.  You had options -SearchBase and -Properties that did not return any results.
